# Sorting panelgrid JSF

Tags: jsf, sorting

Can we sort values in column of a panelGrid. If yes, can I see an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather use `h:dataTable` to represent a dynamic table which is backed by a `List<RowObject>`, wherein `RowObject` is basically just a Javabean (DTO - Data Transfer Obejct, VO - Value Object, whatever you call it :) ) representing a single row.

Such a `List` can be sorted using [`Collections#sort()`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html). All you need to do is to implement a [`Comparator`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) which takes care about the ordering. Then in the JSF page just have a bunch of buttons or links which calls `Collections#sort()` on the `List`. Those buttons/links just have to pass the sortfield along.

You can find here a basic example: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/using-datatables.html#SortingDatatable

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. `<h:panelGrid>` = `<table>`

If you want sorting, look at [Richfaces](http://www.jboss.org/richfaces) or another component framework (Icefaces, primefaces, trinidad, tomahawk, etc). There are `<x:dataTable>` components there which allow sorting on their `<x:colum>`.

Comment: Even in those cases, you're usually sorting on a DataTable. PanelGrids are used primarily for layout.